# Restricting Web Sockets to LAN network

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, lan

Is it possible to restrict HTML5 WebSocket to a LAN network?

For example, I would have a live website, at http://example.com, and all users on the same local network would need to be treated as a group. Similarly, these same users would NOT be able to see or affect any actions of users outside of the LAN.

I have looked into wrappers such as NowJS, and this has built-in support for "groups", but I'm not sure if this is what I'm after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the user's IP address, you could check if the first three segments are same and use that as a grouping criteria. But I guess that might work ok only with office LANs without NAT.